# Why is my add class on hover working on Jsfiddle but not on my website? Am I missing something in my header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class on hover to animate my class using keyframes. I have the whole thing working on jsfiddle but it doesn't add a class on my webite that has the exact same code. Do you need to include something in your header file to use javascript? Sorry if I sound like a huge noob. I am.

```
$(".sponsorDescription").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("fade");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e27Dt/1/#&togetherjs=kEoBqL8yHd

Website
http://www.theridgefarm.com/sponsors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self-executing, anonymous function that creates a closure where $ is set to jQuery. You can use it without worrying about the $ namespace polluting the global namespace and therefore not accidentally use the $ from some other library.

```
(function($) {

  $('.thing').method('set');

})(jQuery);
```

This is a general WP practice. You can also use `jQuery(` like @Okomikeruko said - but that can be tedious when writing it many times. If I'm not mistaken, I think it's also like a document.ready?

`( )` means execute function/method "call" right?

and so, `(  function() {}  )();`

`(  function($) {}  )(jQuery);`

Maybe this will help understanding the syntax. : )

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WordPress?

WordPress does funny things to jQuery, like invalidating the `$` prefix. Try this:

```
jQuery(".sponsorDescription").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("fade");
});
```